# Changing the homepage from default.aspx to abc.aspx

Tags: .net, asp.net, html

i have designed my homepage of my webpage as abc.aspx not default.aspx . How can set the abc.aspx as homepage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set ***default document in IIS*** for a particular web site.

Answer (score 1):

Although you can change the default document using IIS Manager, as others have said, I prefer to do it directly in web.config, since I don't have every site configured to use IIS in my development environment.  For example:

```
<system.webServer>
  . . .
  <defaultDocument>
    <files>
      <clear/>
      <add value="abc.aspx"/>
    </files>
  </defaultDocument>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

If using Visual Studio you can right click on the page and select *Set as Startup Page*. In IIS you can add it to the *Default Document* list, ensure you put it first in the list.

Answer (score 0):

add abc.aspx in default document list in ISS.
then move it to top on list.